# Euler Tour Tree

Tags: algorithm, graph, tree

Recently I read about Euler Tour Tree traversal of any given tree.[wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_tour_technique)

And many articles claim without any explanation, that the resulting array will be of size exactly 2N-1. I tried to prove that by myself but failed. Any ideas ?

Comment: ("Obvious"/"trivial" calls for a [constructive proof](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructive_proof) or [proof by contradiction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_contradiction).)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since, the number of edges in a tree is N-1 and we transform each edge in two directional edges -> the number of edges = 2(N-1).
Therefore, the total number of edges in euler traversal by definition = 2(N-1).

```
|V|=|E|+1 => total number of vertices used during traversal is 2(N-1)+1 = 2N-1.
```

P.S. I know that the question is a bit stupid, but that doesn't mean to decrease points, does it ?

Comment: (One reason to down-vote a question or answer is "not useful" - which I find harsh on questions. I use "I'd rather do without this post".)

Comment: It was down-voted probably because this question doesn't belong to Stack Overflow at all. Cross Validated may be a more suitable place for your question.